# Which compilers support std::filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem, c++17

Thanks to C++11, after a long relationship with boost, the last component that makes me depend on it is the filesystem. std::filesystem seems to be implemented as experimental according to the link: [Filesystem library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs)

Since it mimics boost::filesystem, I can easily adapt my project into std and get rid of huge boost dependency. Which compilers support it and would it matter to use it even though it is experimental since it mimics boost (since there is no time schedule for when it will be standardized)?

Comment: MSVC is the only one I'm aware of, which happens to be a very good reason for continuing to use Boost.Filesystem.

Comment: A better question would be: What platforms/toolchains is std::filesystem supported on?

Comment: Note that there are [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40899267/8586227) to the Boost compatibility in the version ultimately standardized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Visual Studio has been shipping various versions of the filesystem library for a couple of releases. I believe that VS 2013 was the first one to include it.
- libstdc++ shipped their file system library as part of the 5.3 release.
- libc++ has a file system library in development, but it will not be part of the upcoming 3.8 release.

Note that `std::experimental::filesystem` is not yet part of the C++ standard, but rather defined in a Technical Specification. This means that they are subject to change before they become part of the standard.  (which is why they are in the `std::experimental` namespace)

Comment: VS2012 shipped it first, but that implementation was honestly too scary to use.

Comment: Libc++'s implementation *will* be part of the 3.9 release.