# How similar are Boost.Filesystem and the C++ standard filesystem library?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, std, boost-filesystem

I need a filesystem library for use with a C++11-capable compiler or a C++14-capable one - so it can't be be  from C++17.

Now, I know  that the filesystem library going into C++17 is based based on Boost::Filesystem; but - are they similar enough for me to use the Boost library and then seamlessly switch to the standard version at a later time, without changing more than, say, a `using` statement? Or are there (minor/significant) differences between the two? I know that for the case of `variant`, the Boost and the standard library versions differ quite a bit.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a number of differences.  Some were, I believe, Boost changes that were never propagated.  For example, there is no `path.filename_is_dot()` query (as discussed below, it would be less useful in `std::filesystem` anyway).

There was also a good bit of late-breaking news on this front:

1. Support for [non-POSIX-like filesystems](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0430r2.pdf):

   - Specify whether a string is OS-native or POSIX-like (or let the implementation decide, which is (still) the default)
   - An implementation may define additional file types (beyond regular, directory, socket, *etc.*)
   - An implementation may define `file_size` for a directory or device file
2. [`filename()`, normalization, and relative/absolute conversions redefined](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0492r2.html) (examples for POSIX):

   - `path("foo/.").lexically_normal()=="foo/"` (is the opposite in Boost)
   - `path("foo/").filename()==""` (is `path(".")` in Boost)
   - `remove_filename()` leaves the trailing slash and is thus idempotent (it assigns `parent_path()` in Boost)
   - `path(".profile").extension()==""` (is the whole name in Boost)
   - `path` decompositions and combinations can preserve things like [alternate data stream names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) that are normally invisible
   - `path("foo")/"/bar"=="/bar"` (is `path("foo/bar")` in Boost), which allows composing relative file names with others (absolute or relative) and replaces Boost's `absolute()`
   - Boost's `system_complete()` (which takes only one argument) is renamed to `absolute()`
   - `canonical()` thus takes only one argument (fixed in a [DR](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0699r0.html#2956))
   - `lexically_relative()` handles `..` and root elements correctly
   - `permissions()` takes more arguments (Boost combines them into a bitmask)

Note that Boost.Filesystem v4 is [under development](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/commits/v4) and is supposed to be C++17-compatible (but therefore incompatible in many respects with v3).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit beyond just linking? Also, have these changes not applied also to Boost filesystem?

Comment: So, is Windows' filesystem considered "non-POSIX" because of the drives and the backslashes? Or are we talking about something else?

Comment: Windows "is POSIX" despite the drives (which actually have a POSIX analogy in `//worms/share/foo`) and backslashes, but only because certain unusual things like ADS names are either ignored or hidden by the implementation.  ("Non-POSIX" includes things like "has no relative paths" or so.)

Comment: C:\ is a perfectly fine filename in POSIX, and I am reasonably sure windows can't handle that and many other POSIX filenames and features, so while it can be emulated, windows (the win32 subsystem) is certainly not POSIX.

Comment: @MarcLehmann: Sure, but how does that affect the statement that, for the purposes of file system *structure*, this interface considers it POSIX-like?

Comment: List of differences is much longer. For example, function `copy_directory()` does not even exist in std::filesystem.

Comment: @BЈовић : It was changed into an overload of `create_directory` as the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#copy_directory) said it should be.  I don’t know if that warrants specific attention or not.

Answer (score 8):

**Caveat:** This answer does not reflect several last-minute changes before C++17 was finalized. See @DavisHerring's answer.

---

The Boost filesystem inserter and extractor use `&` as the escape character for `"` and `&`.

The standard will use [`std::quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) (which uses `\` by default) to escape `"`, which in turn use `\\` to escape `\`, see [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt).

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AVEb1HBf4rUJQXaL)

It is likely the only one difference between them.

The reason for that difference can be found at [N3399](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3399.html)

Comment: I'm not really finding an explanation at the link for why use & at all as an escape character, that seems very weird to me. But thanks.

Comment: @einpoklum The Boost folk had used `&` for a long time, I don't know why they chose it, it's unlikely they will change it. The standard folk want to make it consistent across all library.

Comment: "It is likely the only one difference between them." This is far from correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another nasty difference:

```
if (!std::filesystem::exists("/I/dont/exist", error)) {
    if (error) <-- this is **false**
}

if (!boost::filesystem::exists("/I/dont/exist", error)) {
    if (error) <--- this is **true**
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but - please add an explanation of why that is.