# How to replace the base parameter removed from boost::filesystem::weakly_relative and std::filesystem::canonical

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-filesystem, std-filesystem

The function `boost::filesystem::canonical()` ([doc of 1.66](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical), [doc of current release](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical)) offers two arguments (ignoring the error code overload) `base`. The first one is the path to canonicalize, the second argument is the base path used to make the first path absolute if it is relative. By default [current_path()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#current_path) is used for this argument.

Boost 1.60 introduces some new functions, among them `boost::filesystem::weakly_canonical()` ([doc of 1.66](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#weakly_canonical), [doc of current release](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#weakly_canonical)). This function is missing this second argument. The same is true for the standardized (C++17) variants `std::filesystem::canonical()` and `std::filesystem::weakly_canonical()` (see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical)).

I want to exchange `canonical()` with `weakly_canonical()`, but I used the second argument. That is how I realized that this argument was removed. Now I'm wondering why it was removed and how I can make the path absolute myself.

I found a [defect report](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2956) which hinted to [this resolution for C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0492r2.html#US78), but frankly I don't really get the rationale. I'd be happy about an explanation or maybe better an example where the overload with base would be overspecified.

And of course I'm wondering how I then should convert a relative path into an absolute path using a base directory which is not the current directory. Should I simply use `base / p` as hinted on [cppreference for `std::filesystem::absolute()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/absolute) because I know that this is the correct form on my target system (Windows with Visual C++)?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How similar are Boost filesystem and the standard C++ filesystem libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899267/how-similar-are-boost-filesystem-and-the-standard-c-filesystem-libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here are the circumstances that you might have when you have a relative path and want to call such a function:

1. You know the path is relative to the `current_path`.
2. You know the path can be made absolute by calling `absolute`. Note that thanks to filesystems like Windows, this is *not the same thing* as saying that it is relative to the `current_path`.
3. You know the path is relative to some known `absolute_path` which is not the current path.
4. You don't know if the path is relative or not.

In case #4, your first step needs to be to find out whether it is relative and if so what it is relative to. Once that is done, you're back to cases 1-3.

In each of the cases 1-3, you have a direct way to compute the absolute path. In case 1, you use `current_path() / rel`. In case 2, you use `absolute(rel)`. In case 3, you use `absolute_path / rel`. (note: This is not only "the correct form on my target system (Windows with Visual C++)", this is the correct form *period*.)

In the original version of `canonical/weakly_canonical`, the functions only handled cases 1 and 3. Case 2 was impossible to handle within the function. By making the functions lower-level, by making them use `absolute` for relative paths rather than taking a base path that defaults to `current_path()`, this allows the functions to handle case 2 as well as the other cases.

They could have changed it so that there would be overloads that don't take a path (rather than a default `current_path()`) which would use `absolute`. But really, what's the difference between `canonical(rel, absolute_path)` and `canonical(absolute_path / rel)`? Indeed, the latter makes it much clearer what you're doing, since it puts the absolute path on the left, which is where it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess my main problem is that I don't see the difference between 1 and 2. Is there any example you could give? Do you refer to NTFS with "filesystem Windows"? And if `abs_path / rel_path` is _the_ correct form, why then the non-POSIX hint in cppreference?

Comment: The note in cppreference is for a *specific case*. It's saying that `absolute` behaves that way on POSIX filesystems. But on Windows (for example), it doesn't. That's the point. As for the difference between 1 and 2, that's a matter of the fact that there isn't always a single "current path" on a filesystem. `d:myfile.txt` is a relative path. Its proper absolute version uses the current path that the `D` drive is currently using. That's not necessarily the same as what you get from `current_path`. In Windows, each driver has a separate current path.

Comment: Is the problem relative paths with root names such as `"D:file.txt`? When `current_path() == "C:\\local"` then `absolute("D:file.txt")` might return `"D:\\local\\file.txt"` whereas `path("C:\\local") / path("D:file.txt")` returns `"C:\\local\\D:file.txt"`? (at least that's the result with boost 1.56 on Windows, with [Microsoft's std::tr2::sys implemenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874769.aspx) and with Microsoft's implementation of `std::experimental::filesystem`)

Comment: OK, so that **is** the problem. (didn't see your comment in time) Never thought of such kind of relative paths. Thank you very much.

Comment: But given `abs == path("C:\\local") != current_path()` and `rel == path("D:file.txt")` then there is no function that would return `"D:\\local\\file.txt"`, I could only use `abs / rel` to retrieve the illegal path `"C:\\local\\D:file.txt"`. I guess we'll have to live with that.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl: "*then there is no function that would return "D:\\local\\file.txt"*" Why would there be? The current path on `D:` is probably not `D:/local`. So why would a function ever return that? You need to ask yourself the question, "what does `D:file.txt` mean to the person who gave it to you?" It almost certainly *does not* refer to a file in `C:`, since they went through the trouble of explicitly specifying `D:`.

Comment: Of course, you are absolutely right. So the best idea might be to test for `rel.root_name().empty()` and do something meaningful in case it is not.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl: Or, you can just use `absolute`. That's *why it is there*.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl `path("C:\\local") / path("D:file.txt")` is `path("D:file.txt")`.

Comment: @NicolBolas I can't because the base directory usually is not the current directory (of that drive). base is the parent directory of one file which is referencing other files, possibly with relative paths. I need to make these paths absolute. That's the whole reason for my question for my question after all.

Comment: @T.C. Not true, at least not for the implentations I tested. I did not simply state the result of [comment #3](#comment83467854_48230478). The result of `path("C:\\local") / path("D:file.txt")` really is `path("C:\\local\\D:file.txt")`. This is also true for libstdc++ on POSIX systems, see [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5aae257eeac599c8) on coliru. (also showing a bug in the libstdc++ implementation)

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl I'm telling you what C++17 says `operator /` produces.

Comment: @T.C. I see, (given `p = path("D:file.txt")`) although `!p.is_absolute()` still `p.has_root_name()` (at least on windows, on a POSIX system this should return false, and it is on coliru) and root names are different. Sorry for my reaction, using a small comment such as "standard mandates that" would have helped me. I now realize that the reason is that I only tested implementations of `std::experimental::filesystem` for which (at least according to cppreference) `append()` was specified differently. Thanks for clarifying this.