# c++ fs::path's operator/ counterintuitively overwrites entire path. A solution?

Tags: c++

```
fs::path p1 = "/q/b";
fs::path p2 = "/";
std::cout << p1 / p2 << std::endl;
```

[will output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55214156/why-does-stdfilesystempathappend-replace-the-current-path-if-p-starts-with) `/`.

It is totally unexpected from so many perspectives:

- **Purely logical**: [**appending**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) (that is how the operation is called, right?) something to something cannot overwrite the former.
- **Current Unix path behaviour**: for Linux "/a/b" is the same as "/a/b/", "/a/b//", ..., so anyone who works with it would expect *appending* behaviour, as opposed to *overwriting*.
- **Safety**: Dangerous things (erasing an existing value of `fs::path`) should be much harder to do than safe/non-destructive things (just adding to an existing value of `fs::path`). In other words, the current behaviour relies only on somebody's *manually* checking what is going on. If you forgot to write a check (whether a path starts from `/`) - you are out of luck.
- **Finally**: I do not think a person who just wants to overwrite a path, will use `/` instead of `=`.

---

**My primary question**, however, is what the supposed solution is? Please, imagine `p2` path comes to you as an argument of a function, it might be `/` or `c/d` or `c`.

Some (awful) options I see:

1. I can just remove the first if in sources of libcxx:

```
  path& operator/=(const path& __p) {
    if (__p.is_absolute()) {
      __pn_ = __p.__pn_;
      return *this;
    }
```

2. Continue using `operator/` - but if I want more compliant with Linux behaviour I need to have some checks?
3. Use [`concat, operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/concat) - but it will not add separator `/` in case of `fs::path("a") + "b"`.

Ideally I would like to overwrite the `operator/`...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the safety concerns I described in the question (it is just dangerous to have destructive/overwriting behaviour in so innocent looking operation - `path1 / path2`), I decided that the best option will be to just fork the current `std::filesystem::path` as a new type and rectify the code of `operator/`.

[Here you can find one-header implementation](https://gist.github.com/DimanNe/d823bee7608f3c3c8b1aa7adac88d178), almost all of which is taken from from clang's `libcxx`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not counterintuitive because you are not concatenating string, You are appending one path to another. `fs::path{"/"}` does not represent the character `/` nor the folder separator delimiter. It represents **the root path**. The behavior of the [`path::append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) (and [`operator/(path)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_slash))
is that if the second operand is an absolute path then the result is the second operand (here it can be made a case that an exception should have been thrown instead).

If you want to append the directory separator you can do this:

```
fs::path p1 = "/q/b";
fs::path p2 = "./"; // <-- relative path

std::cout << (p1 / p2).lexically_normal() << std::endl;

// or this
std::cout << p1.concat("/").lexically_normal() << std::endl;
```

The [`path::lexically_normal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal) is there to normalize the result so that for the general case you don't get weird paths like `/q/b/./` or `/q/b//`.

Comment: Of course, I can see their reasoning (who was designing the class), from my experience, however, the default was chosen wrongly. I think so, because standard ought to correspond/describe and fit well the world. The world (and here I mean Linux) behaves differently. In Linux it **is** a concatenation of strings.

Comment: Also, I clarified a bit my question. The problem is that p1 and p2 are arguments of a function. I cannot prepend "." to p2 always. What if p2 is "a"? I could remove leading / from p2 if p2 is absolute, but it means the complexity will be doubled... And it also means I cannot use very convenient operator/ ... :(