# filesystem::operator/ different behaviour in boost and std

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, std

I am trying to port from `boost::filesystem` to `std::filesystem`. During the process I encountered some code in which `boost` and `std` seems to behave in a different way.

The following code shows the behaviour:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

template<typename T>
void TestOperatorSlash()
{
    const std::string foo = "Foo";
    const std::string bar = "Bar";
    const T start = "\\";
    std::string sep;
    sep += T::preferred_separator;
    const auto output = start / (foo + bar) / sep;
    std::cout << output << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TestOperatorSlash<std::filesystem::path>();
    TestOperatorSlash<boost::filesystem::path>();
}
```

The code gives in output:

```
"\\"
"\FooBar\"
```

The expected behaviour for me is the one of `boost`, and I don't understand what happens with `std::filesystem`.

Why do I get `"\\"`?
Why is the behaviour of `operator/` of `path` different in `boost` and `std`?

### Edit:

After understanding the motivation of the behaviour of `std::filesystem::operator/` and given the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55214156/why-does-stdfilesystempathappend-replace-the-current-path-if-p-starts-with) question, I decided to use the function `path::relative_path()` for the second argument of `operator/` when I have an absolute path.

In this way I can mimic the behaviour of `boost::filesystem`.
So, for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    fs::path foo = "\\foo";
    fs::path bar = "\\bar";
    auto foobar0 = foo / bar;                   // Evaluates to \\bar
    auto foobar1  = foo / bar.relative_path();  // Evaluates to \\foo\\bar
}
```

Comment: If you want to generate a final `/` in a `path`, you can use `/ ""`, which produces a result that is of course one character shorter than using `/ "a"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost will merge redundant separators.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-appends

> Appends path::preferred_separator to pathname, converting format and
> encoding if required ([path.arg.convert]), unless:
>
> ```
> an added separator would be redundant, ...
> ```

Whereas std::filesystem sees a leading separator in the second argument of `/` as an instruction to replace parts or all of the original path:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append

```
path("C:foo") / "/bar";  // yields "C:/bar"        (removes relative path, then appends)
```

Did you want:

```
const auto output = start / (foo + bar) / "";
```

instead?

Comment: I was not aware of the 'replace' mechanism of `std::filesystem::path::append`. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55214156/why-does-stdfilesystempathappend-replace-the-current-path-if-p-starts-with) some explaination about it. Thank you for your answer.