# Which versions of GCC and clang support std::filesystem/std::experimental::filesystem?

Tags: gcc, clang, c++17, std-filesystem

I'm using *GCC 7.4.0* and *clang 6.0.0* and they both seem to have an implementation of *filesystem* in `<experimental/filesystem>`.

since the project that i'm working on requires std::filesystem, i want to know which versions (Major + Minor) of them support it, and in which versions is it implemented in `<experimental/filesystem>` and `<filesystem>`.

so that i can handle the `#include`s and `namespace`s correctly, and also throw in some `#if`s to avoid trying to compile the project with an unsupported version of the compilers

Comment: Thanks for the info. but what about ```std::experimental::filesystem``` (which is what i'm using now), when was it introduced?

Comment: Be warned that using `experimental/filesystem` is [a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40899267/8586227) from the C++17 version.

Comment: That's interesting. i guess i'll have to invest some more time studying the implementation to avoid extra debugging sessions!

Answer (score 1):

I note that GCC is a compiler system that is separate and distinct from the Standard Library ( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standard-Libraries.html ).

That said, GCC 8.0 includes the `std::filesystem` library - but your project needs to be in C++17 mode to use it.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_headers.html#manual.intro.using.headers.cheaders

> Table 3.9, “C++ 2020 Library Headers”
>
> - `any`
> - `charconv`
> - `execution`
> - `filesystem`
> - `memory_resource`
> - `optional`
> - `string_view`
> - `variant`
>
> shows the C++17 include files. These are available in C++17 compilation mode, i.e. `-std=c++17` or `-std=gnu++17`. Including these headers in earlier modes will not result in compilation errors, but will not define anything. Unless specified otherwise below, they are also available in later modes (C++20 etc).

w.r.t. your specific question:

> Thanks for the info. but what about `std::experimental::filesystem` (which is what i'm using now), when was it introduced?

The release history for G++ says it was included in version 8.x (bold emphasis mine):

https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html

> Improved experimental support for C++17, including the following features:
>
> - Deduction guides to support class template argument deduction.
> - **`std::filesystem` implementation.**
> - `std::char_traits<char>` and `std::char_traits<wchar_t>` are usable in constant expressions.
> - `std::to_chars` and `std::from_chars` (for integers only, not for floating point types).